# selecting item in one list, other list should also show the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two identical lists in my html code and I want that if I select an element in one list then the other list should automatically scroll to that element in it, for that I have written the code below but this is not working, means when I click any element in list-1 nothing is going to happen in list-2. I am using chrome browser on windows 8.1. please solve the problem.

this is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#l1 li').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).html();
                $('#l2 li').each(function() {
                    $(this).css('color','black');
                    if($(this).html() == val) {
                        $(this).css('color','red');
                        $('#l2').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
                        });
                    }     
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="l1" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:150px">
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="l2" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:350px">
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at this yourself, and only ask us when you get stuck on a particular problem. Can you show us what you've tried yourself? Can you show us that you've at least googled for tutorials on this subject and read them, and tried the examples... and then tried your own code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#l1 li').click(function(){ //click on element of first list
    var val = $(this).html();
    $('#l2 li').each(function(){
        if($(this).html() == val){ // check if that element is present on the second list
            $('#l2').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
            }); // Now scroll to that element
        }   
    });
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxgf0woe/) for the same.

```js
$('#l1 li').click(function(){
     var val = $(this).html();
     $('#l2 li').each(function(){
       $(this).css('color','black');
      if($(this).html() == val)
        {
       $(this).css('color',val);
        $('#l2').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
        });
        }
         
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <ul id="l1" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:150px">
                <li>red</li>
                <li>green</li>
                <li>blue</li>
                <li>yellow</li>
                <li>black</li>
                <li>orange</li>
                <li>purple</li>
                <li>pink</li>
                <li>grey</li>
                <li>brown</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="l2" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:350px">
                <li>purple</li>
                <li>pink</li>
                <li>grey</li>
                <li>brown</li>
                 <li>red</li>
                <li>green</li>
                <li>blue</li>
                <li>yellow</li>
                <li>black</li>
                <li>orange</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Is it not working in the fiddle or when you implemented the solution in your code. Also which browser are you using?

Comment: I have checked in Firefox/Chrome/IE 11. works fine in all browsers. Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxgf0woe/2/) for better understanding. I have changed the color of the `li` in list 2 for your understanding. Let me know what is creating you the problem.

Comment: when I click any element in list-1, nothing is happening in list-2

Comment: Added a snippet here. Check if its working or not. And please tell according to you what is not working. Or you can open the `Problem Steps Recorder`, record the steps over there and share it with us.

Comment: The code is working perfectly, and I cant see why SajalAli can get it to work.
@Alorika, it is cooler if you chane the css color value to val, so the color of the selected elemet translates to the other list.

Comment: @Zorken17 - I have changed the color of list 2 element on click of list 1 element. Added that in the snippet too. Correct me if I misunderstood your point.

Comment: This is your code: $(this).css('color','red'), change it to this $(this).css('color', val); to get a better effect.